# trying to Write a Python program to create a Caesar encryption

Tags: python, string, encryption

```
string = input("Enter your string ")
for i in string:
     alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" 
     cipher = "ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"
     char = alphabet.find(i)
     ciphered = string.replace(i,cipher[char])
print(ciphered)
```

Any idea why this one only returns the last letter of the string changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the last letter is changed because you are creating a `ciphered` string on each loop from the original input string, therefore on the last loop, only the last element is changed.

```
string = input("Enter your string ")
ciphered = ""
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" 
cipher = "ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"
for i in string:
     char = alphabet.find(i)
     ciphered += cipher[char]
print(ciphered)
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you go through your loop, you substitute one letter in `string`, and then assign the result of that single-letter substitution to `ciphered`, overwriting whatever value it previously had.  The value you get at the end is the value that was assigned during the last loop iteration.

Actually modifying the string in place via `replace` is a bad idea since you'll end up flipping the same letters back and forth.  Instead, you could build up the ciphered string iteratively:

```
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" 
cipher = "ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"
ciphered = ""
for char in string:
    i = alphabet.find(char)
    ciphered += cipher[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should also convert the string into capital letters because otherwise, the find() function can return the value -1.

```
string = string.capitalize()
```